# Rendering / Updating list stored in local storage

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to render a list based on an object called todos. I want this to persist after the user navigates away from the page. When the user adds a to do object, it's saved locally and used update the todos object using state. The todos are not rendering in the list correctly so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

**Todos Object:**

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
  {
    text: "Learn about React",
    isCompleted: false,
    id: uuid()
  },
]);
```

**Add Function (updating todos here which should re render my list):**

```
const addTodo = text => {
  setTodos([{text, isCompleted: false, id: uuid()}, ...todos]);   //updates todos object
  localStorage.setItem("currList", JSON.stringify(todos));        //saves new todos object
  storedCurrList = localStorage.getItem("currList");              //retrieves new object
  parsedList = JSON.parse(storedCurrList);                        //parses object
  setTodos(parsedList);                                           //updates based on local save
};                                                                //object so that the update persists
```

**Component that renders the todos:**

```
{todos.map((value, index) => {
   return(
     <ListItem key={todos.id}> 
       <ListItemIcon>
         <Checkbox
           edge="start"
           checked={value.isCompleted}
           onChange={() => removeTodo(index)}
           tabIndex={-1}
           disableRipple
          />
       </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText disableTypography style={{fontFamily: 'Work Sans', fontSize: 35, color: nightMode.listText}} primary={value.text}/>
     </ListItem>
   );
 })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to render the `todos` from `localStorage` you have to read it first then set that as your initial `todos` state.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]); // todos are empty by default

React.useEffect(() => {
  // reads the todos saved from localStorage and set that as the new value
  // of our todos state — if currList not found, will fallback to empty list
  const savedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currList")) || [];
  setTodos(savedTodos);
}, []);
```

Now when updating the `todos` on `localStorage`, change your `addTodo` handler to

```js
const addTodo = text => {
  // we'll use this to update our `todos` state and `localStorage` 
  const newTodos = [
    { text: input, isCompleted: false, id: uuid() },
    ...todos
  ];

  setTodos(newTodos);
  localStorage.setItem("currList", JSON.stringify(newTodos));
};
```

---

When you do this (the code below) on your `addTodo` function, the `todos` you are setting to `localStorage` is the unupdated `todos` even though you call `setTodos` first.

```js
setTodos([{text, isCompleted: false, id: uuid()}, ...todos]);
localStorage.setItem("currList", JSON.stringify(todos)); // todos here don't have the new todo
```

I created a codesandbox for you to checkout, hope you get the idea.

[image: Edit nice-shirley-mvrnb]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for the detailed explanation you gave me a better understanding of local storage / hooks.